# Does ORMLITE support Table Variable as stored procedure parameter?

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am using service stack ORMLIte for my DAL and so far its working great for basic CRUDS. However, I do have a special case where I have to call stored procedure with parameter type of Table variable. Now, I know that ADO.NET supports this with c# calling the DB with DataTable type. However, I do not know if ORMLite supports it since I did not see any samples in the documentation and if it does, are there any samples out there?

Comment: If the answer given is workable could you mark it accepted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does, here is a sample function that updated to work with TVPs (gets generated using the OrmLite T4 template initially then I modded), hope this helps.  I am passing a HashSet in to use to build DataTable to pass as a TVP Parameter:

```
        public static OrmLiteSPStatement CallMyStoredProcTVP(this IDbConnection db, HashSet<int> userids)
    {
        // need to create a datatable to pass as a parameter to your tvp SP
        DataTable dataTableUserIds = new DataTable();
        dataTableUserIds.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(Int32));
        foreach (int id in userids)
        {
            DataRow ro = dataTableUserIds.NewRow();
            ro[0] = id;
            dataTableUserIds.Rows.Add(ro);
        }

        // create db command
        var dbCmd = (DbCommand)OrmLiteConfig.ExecFilter.CreateCommand(db).ToDbCommand();
        // set name of SP
        dbCmd.CommandText = "MyStoredProcTVP";
        dbCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        // add new parameter but I leave off the Type
        dbCmd.Parameters.Add(CreateNewParameter(dbCmd, "UserIDs", dataTableUserIds, ParameterDirection.Input));
        return new OrmLiteSPStatement(db, dbCmd);
    }

    private static DbParameter CreateNewParameter(DbCommand dbCommand, string paramName, object paramValue, ParameterDirection paramDirection)
    {
        DbParameter param = dbCommand.CreateParameter();
        param.Direction = paramDirection;
        param.ParameterName = paramName;
        param.Value = paramValue;
        return param;
    }
```

Comment: Where is the UDT name?

Comment: @BasilKosovan I am uncertain what you are referring to.. The UDT does not need a name, you simply need a UDT unless you are refererring to ```dataTableUserIds``` which is the instance name.  Sorry, this was 7 years ago so I don't rightly remember